# Problem with Login and reading user information into text filed when the user logged in

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I can't figure out what is the problem, I need you pros to help me with this please. I need it to login by reading their username and password in text file, and load those user information into the text field that store in the text file too. For now my code problem is when I click on Login nothing happen.

Here's my text file information :

```
jack123
jackabc
jc@gmail.com
Jack
123123123
012344567
no1,taman abc.
```

And here is my Login code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LoginButton {


    @FXML
    private TextField txtfUsername;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtfPassword;

    @FXML
    private Button btnLogin;

    @FXML
    private Button btnRegister;

    @FXML
    void setOnLogin(ActionEvent event1) throws IOException{

        String username = txtfUsername.getText();
        String password = txtfPassword.getText();
        boolean grantAccess = false;
        File f = new File("D:\\Apps\\Esclipse\\Assignment\\src\\application\\UserData.txt");
        try {
             Scanner read = new Scanner(f); 
             int noOfLines=0;
             while(read.hasNextLine()){
                   noOfLines++;
             }

            for(int i=0; i<noOfLines; i++){
               if(read.nextLine().equals(username)){
                  i++;
                  if(read.nextLine().equals(password)){ 
                     grantAccess=true; 
                     read.close();
                     break;
                  }
               }
            }
             if(grantAccess){

                Parent root1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("UserGUI.fxml"));
                Scene scene1 = new Scene(root1, 750, 600);
                Stage stage1 = (Stage) ((Node) event1.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

                stage1.setTitle(" Register ");
                stage1.setScene(scene1);
                stage1.show(); 

             }
             else{
                 System.exit(0);
             }
        }
             catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                 e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }





    @FXML
    private void setOnRegister(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("RegisterGUI.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 750, 600);
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

        stage.setTitle(" Register ");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show(); 

    }

}
```

Register code :

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RegisterButton {

    public String Email, Username, Password, Name, IC, Phone, Address;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtfEmailR, txtfUsernameR, txtfPasswordR ,txtfNameR, txtfICR, txtfPhoneR;

    @FXML
    private TextArea txtaAddressR;

    @FXML
    private Button btnRegisterR;

    @FXML
    private Button btnExit;

    @FXML
    private Button btnBack;


    @FXML
    private void OnBack(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoginGUI.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 750, 600);
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

        stage.setTitle(" Welcome ");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show(); 

    }


    @FXML
    void OnExit(ActionEvent event) {

        Platform.exit();

    }

    @FXML
    void OnRegister(ActionEvent e) {

        String line = txtfEmailR.getText() +txtfUsernameR.getText() +txtfPasswordR.getText() +txtfNameR.getText() +txtfICR.getText() +txtfPhoneR.getText() +txtaAddressR.getText() +"\n";

        FileWriter file_writer;
       try {
           file_writer = new FileWriter("D:\\Apps\\Esclipse\\Assignment\\src\\application\\UserData");
           BufferedWriter buffered_Writer = new BufferedWriter(file_writer);
           buffered_Writer.write(line);
           buffered_Writer.flush();
           buffered_Writer.close();

                System.out.println("Registed.");
                System.exit(0);

            }catch (IOException E) {
                System.out.print("Error is ");
            }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are in an infinite while loop since you are calling read.hasNextLine(), but you aren't actually reading the line, so you're stuck at the first line.  You will probably have to put a readLine() in your while loop and then go back to the beginning again to parse the lines.

Edit:

After reading your code, I don't really see a reason for you to have the number of lines, so you could do everything in your first while loop like this:

```
        Scanner read = new Scanner(f); 
         //int noOfLines=0;
         while(read.hasNextLine()){
            if(read.nextLine().equals(username)){
              if(read.nextLine().equals(password)){ 
                 grantAccess=true; 
                 read.close();
                 break;
              }
           }
         }
```

but if you need to know the number of lines for some reason, you could do it like this:

```
        Scanner read = new Scanner(f); 
         int noOfLines=0;
         while(read.hasNextLine()){
               read.nextLine();
               noOfLines++;
         }
         read.close();
         read = new Scanner(f); 
        for(int i=0; i<noOfLines; i++){
           if(read.nextLine().equals(username)){
              i++;
              if(read.nextLine().equals(password)){ 
                 grantAccess=true; 
                 read.close();
                 break;
              }
           }
        }
```

Also, a potential issue I can see with your code is you might get incorrect results if someone's password is someone else's username.

Comment: Something like this?   try {
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\Apps\\Esclipse\\Assignment\\src\\application\\UserData.txt")); 
       int noOfLines=0;
       while(read.readLine() == null){
             noOfLines++;
       }

Comment: I've edited my post with a couple of possible solutions

Comment: Okay! fixed Thank you! can I ask another question hope you could help me, after the login I need the rest of the data in text file to load into the User profile GUI. Any idea?

Comment: When you find the correct username and password, you could keep reading more lines and store those values in variables and display them where you want.

Comment: How to store the rest of the lines in text file and call to display in another class?

Comment: create the variables like you did in registerButton 'public String Email, Username, Password, Name, IC, Phone, Address;'  and then once you confirmed the password you can do 'Email=read.nextLine(); Name = read.nextLine(); etc'  Now they are available publicly from your LoginButton  class.

Comment: Okay, now how do i call it in the ProfileButton class?

Comment: Okay, I know how to call all the variables in ProfileButton Class, so now I need to let the user to edit their profile and save it. Any idea how to set the Action?

Comment: not sure actually.  I've never used javafx.  I've just been using my knowledge of java to answer your questions.